# How to make 2 buttons work together in Java script that are getting created by a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to display data from a java servlet to a jsp. I have this map which I am transferring to the jsp and I am looping on it so that I can get the data.  I am displaying the key value in a span tag and the "value" in the button. With a loop there is generated dynamically buttons. When the user clicks on the button, I am sending the data through Ajax and I am getting the data to show on the jsp page. Then, I want the button to get disabled once it is pressed and it will be enabled again if a different button is pressed.

**JSP PAGE**

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Doctor's Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        <%@include file="/CSS/doc.css"%>
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/JS/doc.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="upcomingAppointments">
    <span class="text">Upcoming Appointments</span><br><br>
    <form id="form" name="form">
            <c:forEach items="${dates}" var="element">
                <span class="date">${element.key}</span>  <input type="button" class="mybtn count" value="${element.value}"><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="dateSelected" value="${element.key}">
            </c:forEach>
        </form>     
    <div id="patientDetails" style="display:none"></div>    
    </div>
    <c:if test="${not empty noAppt }">
        <span>${noAppt }</span>
    </c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS PAGE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //Stops the submit request
    $("#form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //checks for the button click event
    $(".mybtn").click(function(e){  
        
        //get the form data and then serialize that
        dataString=$("form").serialize();

        //make the AJAX request, dataType is set to json
        //meaning we are expecting JSON data in response from the server
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Doctor_Appointment_Application/Login",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            
            //if received a response from the server
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                //doc Name was correct so we have some information to display   
                    $("#patientDetails").show(500);
                    $(data.pDetails).each(function(index,item){
                        var img=document.createElement('img');
                        
                        img.src=item.userImage;
                        img.className+="image";
                        
                        $("#patientDetails").append(img);
                        $("#patientDetails").append("<b>Full Name:</b> "+item.fName+" "+item.lName+"<br>");
                        $("#patientDetails").append("<b>Mobile:</b> "+item.mobile+"<br>");
                        $("#patientDetails").append("<b>Email:</b> "+item.email+"<br>");
                        $("#patientDetails").append("<b>Slots:</b> "+item.slot+"<br>");

                    });
             },
                
                //If there was no resonse from the server
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
                },
                
                beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
                    //adding some Dummy data to the request
                    settings.data += "&dummyData=whatever";
                    //disable the button until we get the response
                    $('.mybtn').attr("disabled", true);
                },
                
                //this is called after the response or error functions are finsihed
                //so that we can take some action
                complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                     
                    $('.mybtn').attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }); 
     });
});
```

**CSS PAGE**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}

.text{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 550;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px;
}

.date{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.count {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:1.5%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.image{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 20%;
    box-shadow: -15px 10px 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    width:180px;
    height:160px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    margin: 20px 50px 30px 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

As you can see, I have disabled the button in the complete function, I did that because whenever I was clicking on the button, it was sending the request again and the data was getting displayed again.
So that is why I need to disable the button once it is clicked.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You could try radio buttons in HTML, they sort of already have the behavior you're interested in. You could listen to a change event on the form, and clicking the same button again wouldn't result in an AJAX request, since nothing changed.

Comment: I would be a lot easier to help you if you just included your generated HTML code and jQuery or Javascript and maybe even your CSS. Check these two fiddles out.  https://jsfiddle.net/nbj1s74L/ https://jsfiddle.net/cthangaraja/e9e50jht/2/

Comment: Hi @timotgl It's a good idea but I don't want to use a radio button, I want to use a normal button.

Comment: @quantumPuter Hi, I added the CSS you can check it out in the question and the HTML code and jquery code is already in the question

Comment: Make your code runnable on stackoverflow and you'll get a much better response.

Comment: Why you have all your element inside one form ? Are you able to pass correct value to backend ? Move your form tag inisde `c:foreach` so that different form will get generated for all inputs .

Comment: @Swati that doesn't make a difference. It's still displaying the data again and again on clicking

Comment: @SamanyuMehra You can style radio buttons to look like normal buttons via css. What I meant was that this would give you the behavior of only one value selected at a time. I guess your question is answered now anyway. Just as some general advice, sometimes a combination of default form input behavior and css solves these types of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i already said in comment make that changes and then you just need to use `$(this).closest("form").serialize();` to get closest form data and then simply use `$(".mybtn").not($this).attr("disabled", false);` to enable all button and not the button which is pressed.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Stops the submit request
  $("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  //checks for the button click event
  $(".mybtn").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this)//use as selector
    dataString = $(this).closest("form").serialize(); //get closest form only 
    console.log(dataString)

    /*  $.ajax({
       //your codes
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {*/

    $this.attr("disabled", true); //set attr disable
    //enable all button not (this)
    $(".mybtn").not($this).attr("disabled", false);
    /* }
    });*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upcomingAppointments">
  <span class="text">Upcoming Appointments</span><br><br>
  <form name="form">
    <span class="date">1</span> <input type="button" class="mybtn count" value="acv"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="dateSelected" value="1">
  </form>
  <form name="form">
    <span class="date">2</span> <input type="button" class="mybtn count" value="avc"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="dateSelected" value="2">
  </form>
  <form name="form">
    <span class="date">3</span> <input type="button" class="mybtn count" value="acs"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="dateSelected" value="3">

  </form>
  <div id="patientDetails" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Swati, that solves one of my problems, my other problem is that I want to hide the form data that was displayed on the click of the first button when the second is clicked.
Like if the first button is clicked it displays "dateSelected=1"
Now if the second button is clicked it should hide "dataSelected=1" and it should display "dateSelected =2". Can you tell me please how to do this

Comment: Hi you mean to remove data which is display inside `patientDetails` div and show new data ?  if yes just empty that div i.e : `$("#patientDetails").html("")`  put this line before `each` loop inside success function .

Comment: YES, THAT WAS GREAT!! THANKS.